# Socket.io Access-Control-Allow-Origin Wildcard

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

So I'm working for a big tech company and we've implemented socket.io in our node server. Since our application handles some security relevant data, our application got checked by some security guys.

They've found out, that on the GET Request of:

```
/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mw3cXXq&sid=something-something
```

the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header is a Wildcard (*). I tried to change it by setting the header as desecribed in the official socket.io documentation. Still, on this URL it keeps being a wildcard.

It this a normal behavior and can be ignored, or is this even security relevant? Sadly I'm not too sure what this URL even is.

Would love to get some answers.

Here the code how I tried to set the origins:

```
// First attempt:
io.origins(['http://mydomain']);
// Second attempt:
io.origins('http://mydomain');
// Third attempt:
io.origins(['mydomain']);
// Fourth attempt:
io.origins('mydomain');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header in your current implementation. Please look at the below code of your of a node express application which details how to set the allowed origins.

```
    var port = 3000;
    var https = require('https');
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.aServerDomain.com");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
      Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });

    var server = https.createServer(options, app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    // start of server
    server.listen(port, function(){
        console.log('listening on *: '+ port + "\n");
    });
```

io.origins is a function that takes two arguments, a string and a callback function where success is a boolean value stating whether an origin is allowed or not. https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-origins-fn

If you're required to use io.origins, you need to do it this way:

```
    io.origins((origin, callback) => {
      if (origin !== 'https://example.com') {
        return callback('origin not allowed', false);
      }
    callback(null, true);
});
```